# ios provisioning profile invalid status

Tags: ios, ios-appstore, development

I have a problem.The provisioning profile account for the developer apple account appears invalid. How can I change this to valid. At the same time, users are using this application. Users should not be affected from this situation. How can I fix it? Help me Thanks
[image: Picture is here]

Comment: Have you contacted [Apple Developer Support](https://developer.apple.com/support/)?

Answer (score 1):

It also happened to me,i deleted it and made a knew one ,with the same bundle id,,resubmit my app with a different build or version after changing provisioning profile,
It didn’t change anything in iTunes connect as far for my app
But,be better be sure send the support an email,or call them
If you are in a hurry,call them they will help you right away ,rather than waiting days for a reply